Get-ScheduledTask only shows full results after piping to Get-ScheduledTaskInfo
I am trying get a list of all the Windows Task Scheduler tasks, to be later filtered by their Action.
I noticed in Both Windows PowerShell and Powershell ISE when running
Get-ScheduledTask
I only get semi results:

But after running Get-ScheduledTask | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo
which returns empty:

And then running Get-ScheduledTask again, it does return full results:

Why does Get-ScheduledTask behave differently before and after Get-ScheduledTask | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo?
Additional details:

From the same session as above (never closed it).



what is your $psversiontable output

try get-command get-scheduledtask and see if you have multiple things defining that. I'm guessing that you have some module other than ScheduledTasks duplicating Get-ScheduledTask that runs initially, and then once you run Get-ScheduledTaskInfo the ScheduledTasks module loads and the correct version runs after that.

PSVersion =  5.1.17763.6054
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source

Function        Get-ScheduledTask                                  1.0.0.0    ScheduledTasks

gcm get-scheduledtask -all

@js2010 same as before. Same one result.

@TheMadTechnician above

@TheGameiswar See above

seems that it doesn't work like I thought. try get-command get-scheduledtas* instead.
